# Referring to a select aggregate column alias in the having clause in Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm migrating from MySQL to Postgres. In MySQL I can use

```
select sum(clicks) c from table where event_date >= '1999-01-01' 
group by keyword_id 
having c > 10
```

Postgres gives an error

> ERROR:  column "c" does not exist

In Postgres I have to repeat the function in the having clause

```
select sum(clicks) c from table where event_date >= '1999-01-01' 
group by keyword_id 
having sum(clicks) > 10
```

There are a lot of places in the code that I have to change. Is there a setting in Postgres that will allow it to use column aliases in the having clause?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a setting in Postgres that will allow it to use column aliases in the having clause?

No. Implementations that allow references to `SELECT`-list entries in `HAVING` are going outside the standard.

You should use a subquery, e.g.

```
select
  c
from (
  select 
    sum(clicks) c
  from table
  where event_date >= '1999-01-01'
  group by keyword_id 
) x
where c > 10;
```

... or repeat the aggregate.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) to achieve the results like below

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT sum(clicks) c
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE event_date >= '1999-01-01'
   GROUP BY keyword_id)
SELECT c
FROM t
WHERE c > 10
```

Comment: Clever, but I'd still have to change the code everywhere.

Comment: @Chloe I just answered because to let you know that another way for your question

Comment: Is this better than a subquery in some way? Being non-standard would be one of the disadvantages of this approach.