# How to use INTO and GROUP BY clause together

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
SELECT cast ( SUBSTRING ( CAST ("ProcessingDate" AS text), 5, 2 ) as integer), 
    COUNT(*) INTO resultValue1,resultValue2
FROM "DemoLogs"."Project" 
WHERE "Addr" = 'Y' AND "ProcessingDate" >= 20160110 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

In my database, the `ProcessingDate` is stored as *YYYYMMDD*. So, I am extracting its month from it.

This query is working fine if we remove the `INTO` clause but, I want to store the result to use it further.

So what should be the datatype of the variable `resultValue1` and  `resultValue2` how to store the data(because data will be multiple).

As I am new to PostgreSQL I don't know how to do this can anybody help me out.

Comment: `resultValue1` & `resultValue2` will be tables not variables.

Comment: @pro_cheats: that depends on where that is executed. For PL/pgSQL those **are** variables.

Comment: @AkshayVakharia: are you trying to create a new table or are you using that code inside a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using inside the PL/pgSQL

Comment: Then show us the **complete** code of the function and the exact error message you get. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: As for the data types: both variables should be `integer` as both expressions are integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the above `query` in the variable and remove that `INTO` clause from it.
So, query will be now :

```
query = SELECT cast ( SUBSTRING ( CAST ("ProcessingDate" AS text), 5, 2 ) as 
        integer), 
        COUNT(*)
        FROM "DemoLogs"."Project" 
        WHERE "Addr" = 'Y' AND "ProcessingDate" >= 20160110 
        GROUP BY 1 
        ORDER BY 1;
```

Now declare **result_data** of type `record` and use in the following manner:

We are looping over `result_data` because it gives number of rows as output

and I have declared `resultset` of type `text` to store the result (as I needed further)

```
FOR result_data IN EXECUTE query
LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE 'result : %',to_json(result_data);
     resultset = resultset || to_json(result_data);
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `resultValue1` & `resultValue2` will be tables not variables. you can group by using the column names.

Give some column alias names for both columns and group by using them.

You probably want this.

```
SELECT cast ( SUBSTRING ( cast ("ProcessingDate" as text),5 , 2 ) as 
integer) AS resultValue1, COUNT(*) AS resultValue2  
INTO <NewTable>  --NewTable will be created with those two columns
FROM "DemoLogs"."Project" 
-- conditions
Group By 1
-- other contitions/clauses
;
```

Kindly refer this [INTO Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can't group by using the column alias.

Comment: Right. Use sub-queries for group by Clause - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32730357/5213405

Comment: Precisely for that reason the non-standard `select ... into new_table ...` is deprecated and `create table ... as select ...` should be used. Inside a PL/pgSQL function `select ... into var1, var2 ...` **does** refer to variables, not to tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name read the documentation of SELECT INTO of PostgreSQL and Explain - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: I did and it says "*CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax*" and "*It is best to use CREATE TABLE AS for this purpose in new code.*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i see, thanks for letting us know. we will follow the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT cast ( SUBSTRING ( cast ("ProcessingDate" as text),5 , 2 ) as integer)resultValue1, 
    COUNT(*)resultValue2  
INTO <Table Name> 
FROM "DemoLogs"."Project" 
WHERE "Addr" = 'Y' 
AND "ProcessingDate" >= '20160110'
Group By 1 
Order By 1;
```